# ConvNetSharp Image Learning

Tags: c#, .net, conv-neural-network, convnetsharp

I am trying to work out how to use ConvNetShar correctly to learn some shapes in some images. I have test data consisting of black shapes on white backgrounds, all these shapes belong to 1 class (road) and I have a mixture of images with that and without. I have tried to adapt the 2d demo and it does seem to learn but when it tests it fails...

Below is my code...just wondering if anyone has a working example with images?

Thanks
(code just updated) seems to be learning..still failing tests though...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ConvNetSharp.Core;
using ConvNetSharp.Core.Layers.Double;
using ConvNetSharp.Core.Training;
using ConvNetSharp.Volume;
using ConvNetSharp.Volume.Double;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using NDNBackpropNnTrainer;

namespace ClassifyImageDemo
{
internal class Program
{
    private static void ClassifyImage()
    {
        string inputFolder = GetInputFolder();
        var filelist = Directory.EnumerateFiles(inputFolder, "*.png");

        List<List<double>> matrix = new List<List<double>>();
        List<int>  expetedList = new List<int>();
        int looper = 0;
        int width = 1;
        int height = 1;
        foreach (var fileInImage in filelist)
        {
            matrix.Add(new List<double>());
            Bitmap source = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(fileInImage);
            List<double> innerList = new List<double>();
            using (var bmp = new LockBitmap(source))
            {
                width = bmp.Width;
                height = bmp.Height;

                for (var y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                {
                    for (var x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                    {
                        var color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                        int myR = color.R;
                        int myG = color.G;
                        int myB = color.B;
                        int total = myR + myG + myB;
                        //Adds new sub List
                        innerList.Add(total);
                    }
                }

            }
            matrix[looper]=innerList; //Add values to the sub List at index 0
            looper = looper + 1 ;
            byte[] myImageRaw = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInImage);
            int len = myImageRaw.Length;
            var lastOneByte = (byte) myImageRaw[len - 1];
            expetedList.Add(lastOneByte);
        }

        var net = new Net<double>();
        net.AddLayer(new InputLayer(1, 1, (width * height)));
        net.AddLayer(new FullyConnLayer(6));
        net.AddLayer(new TanhLayer());
        net.AddLayer(new FullyConnLayer(2));
        net.AddLayer(new TanhLayer());
        net.AddLayer(new FullyConnLayer(2));
        net.AddLayer(new SoftmaxLayer(2));

        // Data
        var data = new List<double[]>();
        var labels = new List<int>();

        foreach (var lstInputs in matrix)
        {
            double[] arrayIn = lstInputs.ToArray();
            data.Add(arrayIn);
        }
        foreach (var lbl in expetedList)
        {
            labels.Add(lbl);
        }
        var n = labels.Count;

        var trainer = new SgdTrainer<double>(net) { LearningRate = 0.01, L2Decay = 0.001, BatchSize = n };
        double loss = 1.0;
        // Training
        while (loss > 0.00001)
        {
            loss = ClassifyImageUpdate(width, height, n, data, trainer, labels);
        }


        // Testing
        var netx = BuilderInstance.Volume.From(new double[(width * height) * n], new Shape(1, 1, (width*height), n));
        for (var ix = 0; ix < n; ix++)
        {
            int subLooper2 = 0;
            foreach (var dtA2 in data[ix])
            {
                netx.Set(0, 0, subLooper2, ix, dtA2);
                subLooper2 = subLooper2 + 1;
            }
        }

        var result = net.Forward(netx);
        var c = net.GetPrediction();
        var accurate = c[0] == labels[0];
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    private static string GetInputFolder()
    {

        return @"D:\temp\filtered\blackroads\subset_500";
    }

    private static double ClassifyImageUpdate(int width, int height, int n, List<double[]> data, TrainerBase<double> trainer, List<int> labels)
    {
        var avloss = 0.0;
        int dimensions = width * height;
        var netx = BuilderInstance.Volume.SameAs(new Shape(1, 1, dimensions, n));
        var hotLabels = BuilderInstance.Volume.SameAs(new Shape(1, 1, 1, n));

        for (var ix = 0; ix < n; ix++)
        {
            hotLabels.Set(0, 0, 0, ix, labels[ix]);
            int subLooper = 0;
            foreach (var dtA in data[ix])
            {
                netx.Set(0, 0, subLooper, ix, dtA);
                subLooper = subLooper + 1;
            }

           // netx.Set(0, 0, 1, ix, data[ix][1]);
        }

        for (var iters = 0; iters < 50; iters++)
        {
            trainer.Train(netx, hotLabels);
            avloss += trainer.Loss;
        }

        avloss /= 50.0;
        Console.WriteLine(" Loss:" + avloss);
        return avloss;
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassifyImage();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The learning loop seems to work quite well, it says its loss gets down to less than 0.0009 which is when I stop it otherwise it jumps back up (I guess this is over learning?). It then goes through the test loop and fails totally....is it not saving the training or something?

Comment: same here, when testing it gives same class for all items

Comment: ok, in my case I had to normalize input (in the range [0;1]) and it started working

Comment: Sorry @ren I know this is from AGES ago but ive just seen it! Im curious what you mean by "normalize input (in the range [0;1])" I have no idea what you mean (99% chance its down to my lack of understanding here)